# How to change default homepage

Tags: settings

My GSM provider hijacked my default homepage and I want to change it. There is no option in android ( nice open system right ? ). So does anyone know how to change it ? Device is rooted.

Comment: Have you tried going to *Settings→Apps*, scrolling to the Browser, open its entry, and "Delete settings"? Note that this would also clear your "other browser data/settings" you might have changed, and most likely also bookmarks, passwords, etc. Alternatively, there are plenty of [Web Browser](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser)s available for Android, so you could simply switch to another ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the default browser that is provided in the android mobiles.

If so, Open your browser, go to settings by pressing the menu button, now go to `General` option and then `set home page` to whatever you like.

```
settings-->General-->Set Homepage
```

Comment: There is entry "Default page" that can't be changed. That's the entry I want to change/remove.

Comment: Your provider may have blocked that setting.

Comment: Device is sim-free. Either way, how do I change it. Where is that information stored ?